# How to update the resolved version of a shared library dependency in a Code Repository?

Tags: python, palantir-foundry

We have a Code Repository that we're using as a shared library.  We recently added some code to it and bumped up the version number.

One of the transformation repositories that we're using seems version locked on the version that was available when we added the dependency (possibly because of the `conda-version.run.linux-64.lock` file that's present in the repository.  That shows it locked in to `0.1.1` and we want it to pick up `0.2.0`).

Here's what we see in the libraries panel for the repo:

[image]

*Is the right move here to delete the lock file and let it get automatically generated or is there some other way to accomplish this?*

Answer (score 2):

After discussion with Foundry support, they confirmed that deleting the lockfile is the right answer:

> if you delete the lock file it will get regenerated with a new a resolution of your `meta.yaml`